# Looping through colors in a canvas

Tags: javascript, arrays, canvas, colors

I'm currently working on some code for my intelligent player.. 
Then i suddenly ran into a problem..
I want the code to display 7 circles with 7 different colors, matching the array "colors". 
When i'm running the code, it will only return the green first color in the array..
Can anybody help me figure out this?

```
var colors = ["green", "blue", "green", "green", "green", "green", "green"]; 
//Store all colors in a array to prevent loads of code
    for (i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
        console.log(colors[i]);
        var centerX = ["325", "475", "625", "775", "925", "1075", "1225"];
        //This will control the x-coordinate of the circles
        for (p = 0; p < centerX.length; p++){
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(centerX[p], centerY, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
            ctx.fillStyle = colors[i%2];
            ctx.fill();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Just so you know, though; the reason you would only ever see green with your code is because you're drawing over the top of what you already drew 7 times, each time with a single colour. The `i` for-loop starts, then you enter the `p` for-loop. You draw using each of the positions in the `centerX` array, and finish drawing. Then you continue to the next value of `i` but restart the `p` for-loop, meaning you draw exactly the same places again. Since your `colors` array ends with green, you only see green.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are making things complicated. Could be done simply as follows ...

```js
var ctx = c.getContext('2d');

var colors = ["green", "blue", "green", "green", "green", "green", "green"];
var centerX = [325, 475, 625, 775, 925, 1075, 1225];
var centerY = 50;
var radius = 20;

for (i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
   ctx.beginPath();
   ctx.arc(centerX[i], centerY, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
   ctx.fillStyle = colors[i];
   ctx.fill();
}
```

```css
canvas { border: 1px solid black }
```

```html
<canvas id="c" width="1300" height="100"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks alot for the help! I really appreciate the fast response! Have a nice evening. :)

Comment: You too `:)­­­­­`

Answer (score 2):

colors[i] is the correct way. I dont know why are trying to use a module of two.

Answer (score 0):

## Objects for associated data

In javascript when you have data fields that are associated it is always best to keep the data in objects.

eg

```
circle = {
   color : "blue",
   posX : "100",  // WARNING!!! Important Note see bottom of answer...
}
```

This makes easier to organize and manage the code, especially as it becomes more complex with more data. Objects can also store other objects. They can also hold behaviours that is unique to that data (or shared between many object types with a common behaviour).

Though creating all the objects this way is somewhat longer than in a flat array, but you can simplify this by creating a function to help.

The following will create a `circles` Object that contains circles and data functions common to circles.

```
const circles = {
     items : [],
     centerY : 50,
     radius : 20,
     add(color, centerX) {  // in objects you don't need to add the function token. This is the same as add : function (color, centerX) {
         this.items.push({
             color, centerX,
             draw(ctx){
                 ctx.beginPath();
                 ctx.arc(this.centerX, circles.centerY, circles.radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
                 ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
                 ctx.fill()
             }
         });
     },
}
```

OR though it might take a little more memory it is more flexible to do it as the following snippet. ( also `x`, and `y` are common abbreviations for positions, and personally I use `r` for radius, `w` for width, `h` for height, `col` for color (colour). Saves you a lot of typing and as long as the only time you use these variable names is when they mean the same thing your code remains (more) readable)

```
const circles = {
    items : [],
    add(col, x, y = 50, r= 20) { // y and radius have optional arguments 
                                 // that are set to 50 and 20 respectively if you 
                                 // don't supply them
        this.items.push({
            col, x, y, r,
            draw(ctx){
                 ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.r, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
                ctx.fillStyle = this.col;
                ctx.fill()
            }
        })
    },
}
```

There are many ways to enter the data but to keep it compact you can create a temp array and enter them from that array

```
[["green",325],["blue",475],["green",625]]
    .forEach(item => circles.add(...item)); // the ... turns an array into arguments
                                            // the missing data x,r are set
                                            // to the defaults.
```

You can also modify the `y` and `r` radius

```
[["green",325],["blue",475],["green",625],["green",775],["green",925],["green",1075],["green",1225,undefined,10]]  // the last item has a different radius
                                         // undefined will set the default value for Y
                                         // and the 10 sets the radius.
    .forEach(item => circles.add(...item));
```

So to do your function using an object, with default values (Note I swapped `x`,`col` as to save me typing in `undefined` when I want the default colour, or you can define a `const U = undefined;` and use `U` (though purist will argue against this, their argument is weak at best))

#### Example

The example defaults the y pos to the canvas height center and set a default circle colour so you don't have to enter green so many times. And just as example I have made the blue circle larger

```js
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
const PI2 = Math.PI * 2; // common use constant values
const U = undefined; // Alias (AKA) undefined
const circles = {
    items : [],
    drawAll() { this.items.forEach(c => c.draw()) }, 
    add(x, col = "green", y = canvas.height / 2, r= 20) {  // default y to canvas center
        this.items.push( {x, y, col, r,  // the order of these make no dif
            draw(){                  // da draw function
                ctx.fillStyle = this.col;
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.r, 0, PI2);  // false is the default last argument so not needed if drawing clockwise                    
                ctx.fill();
            }
        });
    },
};
[[325], [475, "blue", U, 25], [625], [775], [925], [1075], [1225]].forEach(i => circles.add(...i));     

circles.drawAll(); // draw all circles
```

```css
canvas { border: 2px solid black }
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="1300" height="70"></canvas>
```

### WARNING String and Number are not the same.

NOTE from top snippet

```
var a = "100"; // this is a String
var b = 100;   // this is a Number

// The string acts like a number sometimes
console.log(200 / a); // outputs 2 
console.log(200 * a); // outputs 20000

// But it prefers to act like a string if it can and + is a string operation 
console.log(200 + a); // outputs 200100  not 300

// And it can turn numbers to strings as well
b = b + a; // b is now the string "100100"

// A string can be like (==) a number
if(a == 100){ console.log("Yes like a number") }

// But is not a number
console.log(typeof a); // "string" 

// And strictly (===) does not equal any number
if(a === 100){ runEndOfWorld() } // totally safe
```

**Don`t** use a string when you want a number

Comment: Great response! I will immediately look into the look, and try somehow to implement these techniques. :) Thank you!